# Timeout while reasoning about arrays and bitvectors in z3

Tags: arrays, z3, smt, bitvector

I am looking at verifying machine code programs. Since lots of modern SMT solver 
efficiently support arrays, I was planning to use them in our 
verification tool. I was playing around with z3 and I noticed that a 
small change to a formula results in timeout.

Here are the two examples that I used:

1) http://rise4fun.com/Z3/e4Ci
   *Formula: = (array_32_8_0_1_0 == array_32_8_0_0_0) And (EBP_1_1_0 == EBP_1_0_0) And (Not(array_32_8_0_1_0[EBP_1_1_0 - 0] == array_32_8_0_1_0[EBP_1_0_0 - 0]))*
   For this example, I get unsat, which is good!

2) http://rise4fun.com/Z3/t8aT
   *Formula: = (array_32_8_0_1_0 == array_32_8_0_0_0) And (EBP_1_1_0 == EBP_1_0_0) And (Not(array_32_8_0_1_0[EBP_1_1_0 - 1] == array_32_8_0_1_0[EBP_1_0_0 - 1]))*
   For this example, I get a timeout. On my machine running it with 
z3.exe for an hour didn't give me anything as well. This example is 
pretty much the same as (1) except the array access involves a linear expression. (Look at the definition of temp-var-4 at line 16)

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with combination of bit-vector 
and array theories?

Comment: The version of Z3 from the unstable branch solves the formula very quickly.

Comment: So I found out that when I remove the line (set-option :auto-config false) from the examples above, it is able to give 'unsat' without timing out. I don't need to have auto config option, so z3 will work for me. Thanks for the fast reply Nikolaj!